# Using iPhone 4s camera to record video live on OS X

Tags: macos, iphone, camera

I have a late 2010 13" MBP. I have OS X 10.9.5 installed. Also I have iphone 4s. I would like to record video directly from my iPhone's HD camera to my computer since I can't record long videos because I only have 8GB on my iPhone. I tried to use iMovie but when I select the iphone camera, it only shows the videos I have on my iphone. I want to record from the camera directly! However choosing the iSight camera from iMovie, it allows me to record. This is very strange.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Go to App Store put "iPhone webcam" into search and you will find few apps that can help you use your iPhone cam as webcam for you Mac.

Of course every such program relies on desktop client that you need to run or install in order for this functionality to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try screen recording your iPhone from QuickTime while in the camera app.

You might have some issues with being able to see the record button and other UI stuff.

Another little bit of info:
I do this kind of thing sometimes where I AirPlay screen mirror my iPhone to my Apple TV while in the camera app, but I don’t use it to save the video. More of a second screen so I can use the 4K camera and also see what it’s recording.